# JS/Vue: Generating a hash to send to server to compare if data has changed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Right now, I have a button that sends multiple fields of input to my server:

```
axios.post('/send-data' {
    notes: this.notes,
    urls: this.urlArray,
    colorBackground: this.colorBg,
    colorForeground: this.colorForeground,
});
```

After the server receives this, they enter in a queue.  I leave the button active in case they want to update any of the fields, which will update the info in the database and put them at the back of queue again.
The problem is that they can click the button without making changes and it will put them in the back of the queue.  Is there any way I can generate a hash based off of the data being sent, store that hash in a new DB field and then next time a submission is made, see if the hash matches & if so, cancel the update.

Comment: Json stringify is a simplest hast

Comment: As you are using Vue js, why don't you keep the state of the data in the frontend?
I mean a state boolean variable like `isDataChanged` and make the Axios request only if the data has changed.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that, just hash the data in the backend or put a `unique` index on all columns of your table. What problem do you face implementing this?